# Wraping continous text in Itext sharp

Tags: css, itext, word-wrap

I have added code to itext sharp to wrap continuous text. here for example a url.
These css works fine when working in web browser but when I export to pdf the url dont wrap.

I am not able to locate as to what the exact issue is.

Image for reference behavior of the online and pdf view:

[image: Image for reference behavior of the online and pdf view]

Is there any way to wrap the url with css

```css
.background-color-dark-blue {
    background-color: #485679;
}
.color-light {
    color: #fff !important;
}


.white-space-pre-wrap a {
     word-break: break-all !important;
     word-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
   
}
.break-all {
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.url-style a {
    /*font-size: 14px;*/
    line-height: 1.3;
    color: #2a99d4;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
                                                <colgroup>
                                                    <col class="col-3">
                                                    <col class="col-4">
                                                    <col class="col-5">
                                                </colgroup>
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr class="background-color-dark-blue ">
                                                        <th class="color-light">
                                                            Document Name</th>
                                                        <th class="color-light">
                                                            Document Description</th>
                                                        <th class="color-light">
                                                            Location/Link</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    
                                        <tr class="bg-color-lighter">
                                            <td class="va-top">FATF 40 Recommendations</td>
                                            <td class="va-top">Global standard for AML/CFT published by the Financial Action Task Force </td>
                                            <td class="review-report-url-fix  padding-left-5 break-all va-top">
                                                <div class="break-all  va-top">
                                                <a id="SiteContentPlaceHolder_AppendicesReviewControl_ReferenceDocumentListView_ReferenceDocumentLink_0" title="http://www.fatf-gafi.org/publications/fatfrecommendations/
 http://www.fatf-gafi.org/publications/fatfrecommendations/documents/risk-based-approach-banking-sector.html" class="url-style white-space-pre-wrap" href="http://www.fatf-gafi.org/publications/fatfrecommendations/%0d%0a%20http://www.fatf-gafi.org/publications/fatfrecommendations/documents/risk-based-approach-banking-sector.html" target="_blank">http://www.fatf-gafi.org/publications/fatfrecommendations/
 http://www.fatf-gafi.org/publications/fatfrecommendations/documents/risk-based-approach-banking-sector.html</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    
                                        <tr class="bg-color-dashboard-table">
                                            <td class="va-top">Risk Based Approach Guidance for Legal Professionals</td>
                                            <td class="va-top">Guidance on the AML/CFT Risk Based Approach for lawyers and the legal profession</td>
                                            <td class="review-report-url-fix  padding-left-5 va-top">
                                                <div class="break-all  va-top">
                                                <a id="SiteContentPlaceHolder_AppendicesReviewControl_ReferenceDocumentListView_ReferenceDocumentLink_1" title="http://www.fatf-gafi.org/publications/fatfrecommendations/documents/riskbasedapproachguidanceforlegalprofessionals.html" class="url-style white-space-pre-wrap" href="http://www.fatf-gafi.org/publications/fatfrecommendations/documents/riskbasedapproachguidanceforlegalprofessionals.html" target="_blank">http://www.fatf-gafi.org/publications/fatfrecommendations/documents/riskbasedapproachguidanceforlegalprofessionals.html</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>                                   
                                    
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
```

Comment: Just to make sure: Which iText version do you use? 5.5.x with `XmlWorker` or 7.0.x with `HtmlConverter`?

Comment: I just looked at the details of a recent ticket in the iText support system, you are the same customer that reported this. My colleague who is in charge of the issue will give you a solution through JIRA, we will not post a solution on Stack Overflow. You are, however, allowed to copy that solution to Stack Overflow once you got it from us.

Comment: I am using Itext version 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Itext version 7.0 has a inbuild library function

SetSplitCharacters(ISplitCharacters splitCharacters);

So to split characters in Itext 7 use code

```
 public string SplitChars { get; set; } = ".+-/";
var document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.LETTER, false)
document.SetSplitCharacters(new CustomSplitCharacters(SplitChars));
```

so now a continuous url will break at every .+-/ when it is at the end of the table cell

Reffer url for library functions

http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.4/com/itextpdf/layout/ElementPropertyContainer.html